# Why you can't just paste method to make it work?

Tags: java

Given the code..

```
public class test {
    public static void main  (String args[] ) {



        endUp("Hleeloe");

    }

    public static String endUp(String str) {

        if (str.length() < 3) {

            return str.toUpperCase();
            }

            if (str.length() >= 3) {

            String sub= str.substring(str.length()-3,str.length());
            String front = str.substring(0,str.length()-3);
            sub.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(front + sub);
            System.out.println(front);
            System.out.println(sub);
            System.out.println(sub.toUpperCase());
            return front + sub.toUpperCase();


            }

            return str;

            }

}
```

the console:

```
Hleeloe
Hlee
loe
LOE
```

I wanted to have sub.toUpperCase(); to turn the string "sub" into all uppercase letters. But it didn't work. you can see when I print out sub the first time, it is still lowercase. However, when I include the sub.toUpperCase(); within the System.out.println() right before the return, it actually did print out all uppercase letters as shown inside the console.

Why is this? How would I make it work with just the sub.toUpperCase(); part?

Comment: Did you read the javadoc?

Comment: because Strings are immutable

Comment: It probably returns a new string i.e. It doesnt modify the list in.place

Comment: sub.toUpperCase() doesn't do anything by itself

Comment: @redFIVE - Yes it does.  You just have to do something with its output.

Comment: Your best bet is to read the Help Center and learn what it takes to ask a good question. There are a lot of things you could have done to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @johnc. - Questions tend to get downvoted if you can get an answer simply by reading the docs associated with the function.  Maybe it's not fair, but that's just the way it is.  People don't like to spend their time on a question if you can do 60 seconds of research yourself.  StackOverflow should not be the first place you go to get an answer.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't know the word "immutable" even existed for java and I searched for around 20 minutes before posting this question and tried around 4 or 5 different other solutions.

Comment: @Andrew, in this context it does nothing. As in, nothing is assigned to its output. Absolutely no reason to split hairs over that.

Comment: @johnc. Bookmark the javadoc page. Look up the class and method you are using and see what it does. The javadoc is extremely detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` is immutable. so, `sub.toUpperCase()` doesn't change the string internals. It just returns you a new string value that is uppercased:

To uppercase `sub`, rather assign `sub` to the result of the `toUpperCase()` method like so:

```
sub = sub.toUpperCase();
```

That way, you return a new uppercase string.

Answer (score 1):

`.toUpperCase()` does not modify the string it is applied to.

You need to do:

```
sub = sub.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is your code corrected, you don't assign the value in uppercase to the string sub...

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        endUp("Hleeloe");
    }

public static String endUp(String str) {
    if (str.length() < 3) {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
    if (str.length() >= 3) {
        String sub = str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length());
        String front = str.substring(0, str.length() - 3);
        sub = sub.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(front + sub);
        System.out.println(front);
        System.out.println(sub);
        System.out.println(sub.toUpperCase());
        return front + sub.toUpperCase();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: No need to post a silly comment. I removed silly comment, just to keep SO professional. :-)